# Django Form Wizard: How to make a "Confirmation" screen as the last step of your wizard?

Tags: django

Re-posting from an earlier question:

[Django FormWizards: How to painlessly pass user-entered data between forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860392/django-formwizards-how-to-painlessly-pass-user-entered-data-between-forms/14863853#comment20849729_14863853)

I'm using the FormWizard functionality in Django 1.4.3.

I have successfully created a 4-step form. In the first 3 steps of the form it correctly takes information from the user, validates it, etc. In Step #4, it right now just shows a "Confirm" button. Nothing else. When you hit "Confirm" on step #4, does something useful with it in the done() function. So far it all works fine.

However, I would like to make it so that in step 4 (The confirmation step), it shows the user the data they have entered in the previous steps for their review. I'm trying to figure out the most painless way to make this happen. So far I am creating an entry in the context called formList which contains a list of forms that have already been completed.

class my4StepWizard(SessionWizardView):

```
def get_template_names(self):
    return [myWizardTemplates[self.steps.current]]

def get_context_data(self, form, **kwargs):
    context = super(my4StepWizard, self).get_context_data(form=form, **kwargs)
    formList = [self.get_form_list()[i[0]] for i in myWizardForms[:self.steps.step0]]

    context.update(
        {
            'formList': formList,
        }
    )
    return context        


def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    # Do something here.
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/doneWizard')
```

Form #1 has an input field called myField. So in my template for step #4, I would like to do {{ formList.1.clean_myField }}. However, when I do that, I get the following error:

Exception Value:
'my4StepWizard' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

It seems that the forms I am putting into formList are unbounded. So they don't contain the user's data. Is there a fix I can use to get the data itself? I would really like to use the context to pass the data as I'm doing above.

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't any duplicate field names among your three forms, you can use WizardView.get_all_cleaned_data(). It returns a dict of all the data which can be passed on to the template via get_context_data() as you're trying to do. [That's the angle I'm currently taking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912429/how-can-i-show-a-preview-of-all-data-entered-as-a-final-django-form-wizard-step), but I was hoping to find a better way.