# Django; how to forward last form's details to the next?

Tags: python, django

I am fairly new to Django and I am a bit confused about how to make forms work.
I am able to make a single form based on a model I have, but how can I make 3 forms where the second form is generated based on the first form's inputs and the third form is based on the 2nd form's inputs?

For example:

First form: Input your location (city, state, country)
Second form (generated after the first form completed): If country X, then exclude A field in the second form or if the country in the previous form was Y, then exclude B field in the second form.
Third form: similar idea as second form.

Lastly, how do I prevent any database commits until all 3 forms are completed?

Thanks for any inputs!

Comment: What are you looking for is a multiple steps form. There are already similar questions with answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901680/how-to-do-a-multi-step-form-in-django

Comment: Will the user _submit_ a form before proceeding to the next one?  Or are all three forms on the same page?

Comment: multi-step form is exactly what I was looking for! thanks :)