# Doing a Multi-step form with Django Class-based CreateView

Tags: django

I have multiple class-based createviews. My goal is to link all createviews such that when I post the first createview, it will redirect me to the second createview where it will retrieve the data entered from first createview.

Does anyone know the solution to this?

The first createview (Step01) contains django-inline-formset-factory code which is similar to [this](https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d) code, while the rest (Step02 and Step03) contain basic code.

I have referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901680/how-to-do-a-multi-step-form-in-django), but the solution is based on using function-based view. Have also made attempt using Django's Form-Wizard, but handling django-inline-formset with it is still too complicated for me.

Why do I do this? So that each group level (i.e. general, staff, managerial) can access their respective view but not the view for other group level.

This is my current code:

## models.py

```
class Model_Step01_Cart(models.Model):
    cart_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Model_Step01_CartItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Profile)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    item_quantity = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True)

class Model_Step02_Staffnote(models.Model):
    note_staff = models.TextField(max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)

class Model_Step03_Managernote(models.Model):
    note_manager = models.TextField(max_length = 500, null = True, blank = True)
```

## forms.py

```
class Form_Step01_Cart(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_Step01_Cart
    fields = ["cart_name"]

class Form_Step01_CartItem(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_Step01_CartItem
    fields = ["cart", "item_name", "item_quantity"]

Formset_CartItem = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Model_Step01_Cart,
    Model_Step01_CartItem,
    form = Form_Step01_CartItem,
    extra = 3
    )

class Form_Step02(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_Step02_Staffnote
    fields = ["note_staff"]

class Form_Step03(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Model_Step03_Managernote
    fields = ["note_manager"]
```

## views.py

```
class View_Step01(CreateView):
    # contains formset_factory for "Model_Step01_Cart" and "Model_Step01_CartItem"
    model = Model_Step01_Cart
    fields = ["cart_name"]

    # similar with the code displays here: https://medium.com/@adandan01/django-inline-formsets-example-mybook-420cc4b6225d

class View_Step02(CreateView):
    # gets info from step 01, and adds staff's note

class View_Step03(CreateView):
    # gets info from step 01 and 02, and adds manager's note.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Find my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49508982/6340775) to split a single form across multiple views. You can configure the [gist script](https://gist.github.com/bhavaniravi/b784c57ae9d24fce359ae44e2e90b8e3) to fit your requirement

For class-based-view map the success url of one view to other `CreateView.as_view(model=myModel, success_url="/<path-to-view2/")`

Comment: Thanks @Bhavani Ravi. How do I implement your script at class-based view?

Comment: Updated the answer