# Django handle multi step form

Tags: python, django

In multi-step forms what I want to do is when the user clicks on the NEXT button the view should be called in Django and the data is stored in the database and then the next form opens?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901680/how-to-do-a-multi-step-form-in-django here is the answer you want.

Comment: @JordanMicle Thanks but actually I want form like this - https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/multi-step-form-wizard-animated-progressbar-53000683