# Passing user input from one template to multiple other templates

Tags: django

I am learning Django and looking to build out a site that would take input from a user one page1. Then it will pass that information over to page2. Then both page1 and page2 user input would get passed to page3 and processing will happen.

Very similar to like a sign up form. The first page is some information, then the second page is some more information, then the third page will complete the signup.

Right now I return data from one page to another like this:

```
return render(request, 'per/per.html', context)
```

And then on that page I have access to all the data in the context variable. But wanted to know how to move it to another page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do a multi-step form in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901680/how-to-do-a-multi-step-form-in-django)

Comment: Is user authenticated?

Comment: Yes user would be authenticated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Store forms data into sessions and retrieve them on any page.
2. Or store them into database.

Go with database.

[How to use sessions in Django official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/)